# How to create a .dll file with gcc including swi-prolog.h?

Tags: c, swi-prolog

I'm trying to create a .dll file with gcc on Windows 10 and I'm getting an error. The mylib.c file:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "C:/Programme/swipl/include/SWI-Prolog.h"

static foreign_t
pl_say_hello(term_t to)
{ char *a;

  if ( PL_get_atom_chars(to, &a) )
  { MessageBox(NULL, a, "DLL test", MB_OK|MB_TASKMODAL);

    PL_succeed;
  }

  PL_fail;
}

install_t
install_mylib()
{ PL_register_foreign("say_hello", 1, pl_say_hello, 0);
}
```

I included the the swi-prolog.h file because the compiler complained that it can't find the header file like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24602416/problems-interfacing-swi-prolog-to-c).

So compiling doesn't make any problems via:

```
> gcc -c mydll.c
```

But if I want to create the .dll file via:

```
> gcc -shared -o mydll.dll mydll.o
```

I get the following errors:

```
C:\Users\Julian\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAblUMK.o:mylib.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `PL_get_atom_chars'
C:\Users\Julian\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAblUMK.o:mylib.c:(.text+0x76): undefined reference to `PL_register_foreign'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Does anyone know this problem?

Update: I also tried it with swipl-ld, but it doesn't work either. (Just changed the file a little bit, but the issue stays same)

[image]

Comment: Well, it basically doesn't reference swipl's own shared libraries during compilation. Try running swipl-ld with the `-shared` option. See the manpage [here](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=plld)

Comment: I also tried it with `shared` - the same error occurs. Actually in the screenshot above ;-)

Comment: Ah yes. My bad. Does it say more with `-v`?

Comment: Updated my answer with a test on Windows, which comes out successfully.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer thank you so much! Must have been the MinGW that I haven't installed correctly from another [source](https://www.msys2.org/#installation) or that I haven't set right the path variable. Wish you the very best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have a ready.made answer as I have never tried this but this question:

[Building a shared library using gcc on Linux and MinGW on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601949/building-a-shared-library-using-gcc-on-linux-and-mingw-on-windows)

seems to touch on the problem:

> I'm having trouble with generating a build setup that allows shared
> libraries to be built in both Linux and Windows using gcc and MinGW,
> respectively. In Linux, a shared library doesn't have to resolve all
> dependencies at compile time; whereas, this appears to the case in
> Windows.

That being said, the manual says at [Linking Foreign Modules](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=foreignlink) that there is a special **linking tool**:

> This section discusses the functionality of the (autoload)
> `library(shlib)`, providing an interface to manage shared libraries.
> We describe the procedure for using a foreign resource (DLL in Windows
> and shared object in Unix) called `mylib`.
>
> First, one must assemble the resource and make it compatible to
> SWI-Prolog. The details for this vary between platforms. The
> `swipl-ld(1)` utility can be used to deal with this in a portable
> manner. The typical commandline is:
>
> `swipl-ld -o mylib file.{c,o,cc,C} ...`
>
> Make sure that one of the files provides a global
> function `install_mylib()` that initialises the module using calls
> to `PL_register_foreign()`. Here is a simple example file `mylib.c`,
> which creates a Windows MessageBox: ...

However, it seems that you need to add the option `-shared` which is not given above!

The manual for `swipl-ld` is [here](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=plld)

but is given in the context of building a *standalone executable based on
`swipl` libraries and additional C-code*, which is is different.

`swipl-ld` is indeed in the distribution, in the `bin` directory.

Note that you need a "module stub" to introduce the foreign functions to the swipl runtime. Like so:

[image: calling binaries compiled from C from SWI-Prolog]

### Testing whether it works

#### On Linux

Just a short test, but on Linux (I will have to reactive my Windows machine a bit later)

In directory `/home/rost/compilec`:

C-code file `mylib.c`

```
#include <SWI-Prolog.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static foreign_t
pl_say_hello(term_t to)
{ char *a;
  if ( PL_get_atom_chars(to, &a)) {
    printf("Hello, %s\n",a);
    PL_succeed;
  }
  else {
    PL_fail;
  }
}

install_t
install_mylib()
{ PL_register_foreign("say_hello", 1, pl_say_hello, 0);
}
```

Prolog file `mylib.pl` declaring a "stub module":

```
:- module(mylib, [ say_hello/1 ]).
:- use_foreign_library(foreign(mylib)).
```

After the above have been created, build a shared library using
`swipl-ld` by compiling `mylib.c`:

```
$ swipl-ld -v -shared -o mylib mylib.c
```

Output is:

```
eval `swipl --dump-runtime-variables`
         PLBASE="/usr/local/logic/swipl/lib/swipl"
         PLARCH="x86_64-linux"
         PLSOEXT="so"
         PLLIBDIR="/usr/local/logic/swipl/lib/swipl/lib/x86_64-linux"
         PLLIB="-lswipl"
         PLTHREADS="yes"
/usr/bin/cc -c -fPIC -D_REENTRANT -D__SWI_PROLOG__ -I/usr/local/logic/swipl/lib/swipl/include -o mylib.o mylib.c
/usr/bin/cc -o mylib.so -shared -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/logic/swipl/lib/swipl/lib/x86_64-linux mylib.o -L/usr/local/logic/swipl/lib/swipl/lib/x86_64-linux -lswipl
rm mylib.o
```

`cc` happens to be `gcc version 10.2.1` (run `cc -v` to see that)

Now start `swipl` and call the provided predicate.

On the Prolog Toplevel (i.e. the Prolog command line), first extend the search path for foreign libraries:

```
?- assertz(file_search_path(foreign,'/home/rost/compilec')).
true.
```

Consult the "stub module":

```
?- [mylib].
true.
```

Then call the predicate in question:

```
?- say_hello('World').
Hello, World
true.
```

#### On Windows

(More precisely, on Windows 10. Awkward to work with.)

**Get SWI-Prolog**

I have installed SWI-Prolog using the installer available at [Download SWI-Prolog stable versions](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/download/stable), namely `SWI-Prolog 8.2.4-1 for Microsoft Windows (64 bit)`.

After installation has been performed, the SWI-Prolog file tree can be found in `C:\Program Files\swipl` and the `bin` subdirectory indeed contains all we all.

**Get MinGW**

Now get MinGW. This being 64-bit Windows, so we will get the [64-bit version](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php) (which supplants the 32-bit version, and is also being maintained by another team).

Downloads can be found at [this page](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download).

Download the [MinGW64-builds](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download/mingw-builds).

*Sidenote*

I also tried [Win-builds](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download/win-builds) but no luck, the win-builds installer fails trying to download packages because the SHA-3 checksum do not match. Maybe it's too old?

*End of sidenote*

Clicking on [MinGW64-builds](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download/mingw-builds). will redirect us to Sourceforge (ah, nsotalgia!) and will dump an installer into the `Downloads` directory. It passes the antivirus, ESet Antivirus says that it has good confidence in this executable, and computing the SHA-256 checksum then googling it brings good results. Excellent.

So run the installer. I filled in the mysterious settings that it requests as follows:

```
Version 8.1.0     - Latest MingW version
Architecture      - Proposes "i686" (why), switch to "x86_64"
Threads           - "posix" or "win32"? Let's take "posix"
Exception         - "seh", why not, this seems to be the modern exception format
Build revision 0  - Ok I guess
```

(For SEH vs SLJ exception format, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739099/what-is-the-difference-between-mingw-seh-and-mingw-sjlj))

After then download of packages & installation finishes, you end up with a lot of tools in

```
C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin
```

Now we can build our DLL. Open the "Command Prompt" window:

```
> set PATH=C:\Program Files\swipl\bin;C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin;%PATH%

> cd (to where the mylib.c and mylib.pl files reside)

> swipl-ld -v -shared -o mylib mylib.c
```

We see:

```
eval `swipl.exe --dump-runtime-variables`
     PLBASE="c:/program files/swipl"
     PLARCH="x64-win64"
     PLSOEXT="dll"
     PLLIBDIR="c:/program files/swipl/bin"
     PLLIB="-lswipl"
     PLTHREADS="yes"
 gcc.exe -c -D_REENTRANT -D__WINDOWS__ -D_WINDOWS -D__SWI_PROLOG__ -I"c:/program files/swipl/include" -o mylib.obj mylib.c
 gcc.exe -o mylib.dll -shared mylib.obj -L"c:/program files/swipl/bin" -lswipl
 rm mylib.obj
```

and the file `mylib.dll` has been successfully created.

*Sidenote:*

If you check it out on Linux, `file` says that this is a [PE/COFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format) file:

```
$ file mylib.dll
mylib.dll: PE32+ executable (DLL) (console) x86-64, for MS Windows
```

[`nm(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nm) works on the DLL (sweet!) and lists the exported procedure:

```
$ nm mylib.dll  | grep say
000000006e5813b0 t pl_say_hello
```

Well, that DLL file is just a serialized structure like any other,

*End of sidenote*

Can `swipl` use it the DLL? Yes it can!

Start `swipl`. Suppose we have the `mylib.dll` in directory `C:\Users\francisbacon\Documents\Compiling`:

```
1 ?-
assertz(file_search_path(foreign,'C:/Users/francisbacon/Documents/Compiling')).
true.

2 ?-
[mylib].
true.

3 ?-
say_hello('World').
Hello, World
true.
```

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/wiki/How-to-generate-import-library-for-MingW) it's said, that  I don't need that, because the ld linker from GNU Binutils seems to do this linking on it's own. Exactly as [SWIP-Prolog](https://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/LibAndInclude.html) seems to  affirm.

Comment: @Johnny As I understand it, the GNU `ld` is not sufficent on Windows, and you have to use `swipl-ld` to generate the DLL, because of Microsoft Reasons. Have you tried?

Comment: Yes I did, the same error occurs - updated my question^^